# SQL0430N User defined function "SYSPROC.ENV_GET_SYS_INFO"

Tags: db2, upgrade, database-restore, db2-luw

I have restored a Db2 v9.5  database on a new server with Db2 v9.7 FP11 with the same user and with the different user, but got permission error with the instance owner:

```
db2 -x "select os_name, host_name, total_memory 
from table(sysproc.env_get_sys_info()) as systeminfo"
```

> SQL0430N  User defined function "SYSPROC.ENV_GET_SYS_INFO" (specific name "ENV_GET_SYS_INFO") has abnormally terminated.  SQLSTATE=38503.

I have followed all the steps in [this technote](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21568865).

I have set the registry variable as well before restore:

```
[i] DB2_RESTORE_GRANT_ADMIN_AUTHORITIES=ON
```

but still I'm getting the error.

Comment: What appears in the db2diag.log when you run it?

Answer (score 0):

The error has nothing to do with missing authorization. Make sure you [update your 9.5 database](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0054449.html) to the appropriate 9.7 fix pack by running `db2updv97 -d <your db name>`

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved after update the instance

**db2iupdt  -u  instance name**